# TagLib lacks video-metadata properties?

Tags: taglib-sharp

I've been trying to set extended properties of mp4 such as Director and Publisher, but those are nowhere to be found when I browse the File.Tag suggestions that visual studio gives me. Perhaps I'm just using a bad library or something, or could someone confirm that TagLib doesn't support these?

I do however get suggestions for File.Tag properties relevant to audio files such as Album and Performers. Perhaps it's only showing audio properties for mp4? Can you switch to video/movies somehow?

I'm using the windows edition from here: http://download.banshee.fm/taglib-sharp/2.1.0.0/. just dropped the dll in my project dir and laoded it in VC#.

Comment: Have you checked to see if that data is stored in another field?  It is likely that Apple reused the same field for different terms.  TagLib# uses one name per field to identify them.  If not, field identifier can be evaluated in a hex editor and a few lines using `GetText` and `SetText`.